# How to access 2D C++ arrays in x86 asm?

Tags: c++, assembly, multidimensional-array, x86, x86-64

I'm trying to access my 2D array of chars in asm but unsure how it's accessed in memory.

Basically the 2d array is 3 high in the y, and length long (changes in program), and I have a for loop where I'm trying to go element by element in the x for the y=0.

It's defined in C++ as `char array[3][MAXCHARS];`

Then later on element by element in x when y=1. I'm not quite sure how this works, **is the second y value of the array stored straight after the first row of x in memory?**

Comment: Please add a diagram of what you're trying to ask. Right now it's not very clear.

Comment: _"is the second y value of the array stored straight after the first row of x in memory?"_ That's kind of up to you. Or where is this array coming from (who creates it)?

Comment: @Michael  It's defined in the top of the program char array[3][MAXCHARS]; so I'm after whatever that defaults to in cpp

Comment: Ok. Well, if that is C then I believe the ISO standard mandates that the all the elements will be contiguously allocated. That is, the first element of row N will be located right after the last element of row N-1.

Comment: @Michael Okay thanks, it's c++ so that should work

Comment: Fortran stores arrays in column-major order, not row-major like C/C++, so it very much matters how you defined your array.